# Java Multi-Software-Threading always using main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my first time using this website... just tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

`Verk3a` class:

```
package verk3a;

public class Verk3a {

    public static int n = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RunMeSumThread Zack = new RunMeSumThread(n);
        RunMeSumThread John = new RunMeSumThread(n);
        RunMeSumThread Konni = new RunMeSumThread(n);

        Zack.start();
        John.start();
        Konni.start();
    }

}
```

`RunMeSumThread` class

```
package verk3a;

public class RunMeSumThread extends Thread implements Runnable{

    public RunMeSumThread(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" | ");
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And it always returns this:

```
0 | main
1 | main
2 | main
3 | main
4 | main
5 | main
6 | main
```

etc...

I'm trying to make it run multiple threads at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are executing the println() statements in the constructor. The constructors are being executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should pass an implementation of `Runnable` to the super constructor of `Thread`:

```
public class RunMeSumThread extends Thread
{
    public RunMeSumThread(final int n)
    {
        super(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.print(i);
                    System.out.print(" | ");
                    System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should implement the code to be executed by the thread in `void run` method. Just move the logic from the class constructor into the `run` method. Here's an example:

```
public class RunMeSumThread extends Thread implements Runnable{

    int n;

    public RunMeSumThread(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" | ");
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, for thread creating, you should extend from `Thread` class or to implement `Runnable` interface, it's odd to do both at the same time.

In case you extend from `Thread`, there's no need to implement `Runnable` interface. In case you only implement `Runnable`, you should create a `Thread` instance and pass the instance of your `Runnable`. In code (adapted from your code):

```
public class RunMeSumThread implements Runnable{
    int n;

    public RunMeSumThread(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" | ");
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public class Verk3a {
    public static int n = 100;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a Thread and pass an instance of the class implementing Runnable here
        Thread zack = new Thread(new RunMeSumThread(n));
        Thread john = new Thread(new RunMeSumThread(n));
        Thread konni = new Thread(new RunMeSumThread(n));

        zack.start();
        john.start();
        konni.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This could does not work, because `run` from `Runnable` won't take any arguments.

Comment: @JoeInner you're right. Fast typing problems :). Answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

A new "thread" isn't really created (on the OS level) until you call the `start` method of the thread. Since you are printing in the constructor, it always gets executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have added those prints in Constructor.

```
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" | ");
        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println();
```

So It will prints the output while creating objects.

**Note** : Until you call the method `start` its a simple java Object